# "Uncaught TypeError: fs.writeFile is not a function" when using Electron with React

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, electron

I followed [this tutorial](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/building-an-electron-application-with-create-react-app-97945861647c/) to create my Electron/React application and my code is mostly unchanged from the tutorial's. However, I found that I can't load or save files locally, using "fs.writeFile". I get the error "**Uncaught TypeError: fs.writeFile is not a function**", even though the intellisense understands what fs is.

I'm currently using this statement to implement and call fs:

```
const fs = require('fs');

fs.writeFile(JSONFile, window.JSONObj);
```

I'm fairly new to both Electron and React, so I'm not sure how to go about fixing this problem. I've created an Electron app in the past (without React) and didn't have this problem. Any tips on how to fix this would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT:** I finally fixed my problem. Instead of using the tutorial I was originally using, I found [this tutorial](https://www.codementor.io/@randyfindley/how-to-build-an-electron-app-using-create-react-app-and-electron-builder-ss1k0sfer) that shows how to create an Electron/React app that allows the use of "fs". According the article, the problem was that the "electron-renderer" needs to be a "Webpack target".

Comment: Where do you have wrote this code? I think it is on the "client" side of the electron app, you should `const fs = electron.remote.require('fs');`

Comment: I have this code in my main .js file in my src folder. It's written under all of my React imports.

Also, where is the "client" side of an electron app? I'm trying to make an offline electron desktop app.

I'm wondering if the problem is that my app is running on a "localhost:3000", as the tutorial I linked shows.

Answer (score 2):

This tutorial is slightly outdated. Now Electron does not have node enable by default for renderer processes (browser windows). Here is how you can enable that so you have access to node's `fs` API through the created window:

```
new BrowserWindow({

  // your window configuration

  webPreferences: {
    nodeIntegration: true
  }
});
```

Reference: https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window

Please note this change was for security reasons. You could potentially refactor your code to send messages to the main process which in turn could perform the interactions with the file system.

Security Reference: https://www.electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/security

Comment: Hmm, I already had that enabled and it didn't seem to fix anything. It seems like the problem has something to do with running electron on "localhost:3000". In my main.js file for electron, I have "**mainWindow.loadURL('http://localhost:3000');**". If I link this directly to the main .html file (**mainWindow.loadFile('./public/index.html')**) I get the error "**Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module**" However, if I comment out all the React imports, fs works.


Not quite sure how to make React and Electron work properly together.

Answer (score 0):

For me didn't work only with `nodeIntergration: true`. When I set `enableRemoteModule` to `true` and `contextIsolation` to `false` it works without problem. I don't know is this creating some security issues because I am pretty new to this.

```
new BrowserWindow({
  // your window configuration
  webPreferences: {
    nodeIntegration: true,
    enableRemoteModule: true,
    contextIsolation: false,
  },
});
```